# Unable to aggregate subdocument's array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I had documents like the following

need to aggregate latest rating last array element and average(3,1,3,1) it,
here i am stuck up with double unwind unable to get the result

```
{  
Name: name  
Content: [
      {   Rating:[1,2,3]  }    ,   
      {   Rating:[3,2,1]  }
]
},
{  
Name: name  
Content: [
      {   Rating:[1,2,3]  }    ,   
      {   Rating:[3,2,1]  }
]
}
```

Comment: which criteria you set for latest rating element?

Comment: Please improve your question to show on how and on which `rating` element, the average needs to be calculated.

Comment: i just need the average result of each last array element of rating

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I understand that you should find out average of last rating so in your case `Rating:[3,2,1]` will be last rating which you want average, but problem is your Rating data in array as per this two threads [click here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588) and [click here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589)  you should change Rating structure as below

```
 Rating:[{"first":1,"second":2,"third":3}]
```

so using this It will easy to find out average but, If you will not able to change this structure then you should do unwind for two times and it occurred cartesian problem if your collections size limited it will help but for large collections size it takes. I used aggregation and unwind it two times and get avg of last rating code below.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
 {"$unwind":"$Content"},// first unwind on content
 {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","Ratings":{"$last":"$Content.Rating"}}},   
 {"$unwind":"$Ratings"},// Second for remove array element to outside
 {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","avg":{"$avg":"$Ratings"}}})
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh for your quick reply. The solution seems good. But i afraid that the Server will take too much resource if the parent document grows big (in the range of few thousands).